# Installing the sensor simulator application on the emulator

Tags: java, android, simulator, sensors

The site dedicated to the sensor simulator indicates that the `SensorSimulator.apk` application must be installed on the emulator. The problem is I can't figure out installing it.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command line, just type in the following command :

adb install xxx.apk

where xxx.apk is the application to install.

Note : the emulator must be running.